# How to stop interval in js?

Tags: javascript, setinterval, clearinterval

At the moment I'm trying to create a slideshow for pictures (when arrow is clicked, another picture slides in, all pictures are in a row in html). I'm not using scroll method. Images are moving, but seems like I can't stop the interval.
I wanted to ask how to stop the interval? What is something that I'm missing?

```js
const icons = document.querySelectorAll(".icons i");
const imageDiv = document.querySelector(".imageDiv");

let positionRight = 0;

function addPositionRight () {
    positionRight += 1;
    imageDiv.style.right = `${positionRight}%`;
}

icons[1].onclick = () => {
    setInterval(addPositionRight, 10);
    if (positionRight === 100) {
        clearInterval(addPositionRight)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to use `clearInterval` method as follow,

```
const stopInterval = setInterval(addPositionRight, 10);

clearInterval(stopInterval) //<----- use it where you want to stop it.
```

more information: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp

Answer (score 2):

The `setInterval` method returns a pointer to that interval, you then just pass it to the `clearInteral`

```js
const interval = setInterval(() => {
    console.log('inside interval');
}, 500);

setTimeout(() => clearInterval(interval), 2000)
```

Answer (score 2):

setInterval return an identifier which allow you to clear the interval

```
let myInterval;

function addPositionRight () {
    positionRight += 1;
    imageDiv.style.right = `${positionRight}%`;
    if (positionRight === 100) {
        clearInterval(myInterval);
    }
}

myInterval = setInterval(addPositionRight, 10);
```